# Plant Identification - Long stalk, purple flower, growing in grass

Tags: identification, flowers, lawn, wildflowers

Can anybody please help me identify this plant? A number of them were growing in some unmown lawn here in Ireland.

Initially I thought it was a type of speedwell, but I'm not so sure.

Thanks!
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one is called [*Cardamine pratensis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardamine_pratensis) (Cuckoo Flower). Significant features are the pinnate leaf, small leaflets with entire edges, colour (can be pink or white) and the blooming time. The wiki page has a good closeup of the flower, so to check this ID you could compare the flower parts to your plants to see if they match up.

Comment: Ah! You're absolutely correct. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user30092 congratulations, that's a lovely wildflower.